# Finding the solution of a matrix equation via integration

Tags: integration, matrices, derivatives

Consider $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $\Re{(\lambda_i(A))}<0$. For all square symmetric positive definite matrices $Q$ there exists a square symmetric positive definite matrix $P$ such that

$$A^TP+PA=-Q$$

---

The answer provided is:

We may pick

$$P = \int_0^\infty e^{A^Tt}Qe^{A^Tt}\, {\rm d}t$$

as

\begin{align}
A^TP+PA &= \int_0^\infty \left(A^Te^{A^Tt}Qe^{A^Tt} + e^{A^Tt}Qe^{A^Tt}A\right) \, {\rm d}t \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{A^Tt}Qe^{A^Tt}\right) \, {\rm d}t \\
&= \left[e^{A^Tt}Qe^{A^Tt}\right]_0^\infty \\
&= -Q.
\end{align}

---

How is the second step found? By tracing back I find that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{A^Tt}Qe^{A^Tt}\right)=A^Te^{A^Tt}Qe^{A^Tt} + e^{A^Tt}QA^Te^{A^Tt}\not=A^Te^{A^Tt}Qe^{A^Tt} + e^{A^Tt}Qe^{A^Tt}A$$

Comment: I suspect it should be $P = \int_0^\infty e^{A^Tt}Qe^{At}\, {\rm d}t$.

Comment: @copper.hat even so, you still get $$A^Te^{A^Tt}Qe^{At} + e^{A^Tt}QAe^{At}$$ which is not correct.

Comment: I think copper.hat is right as $e^{At}A=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (At)^k/k! A=Ae^{At}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi(t) = e^{A^T t} Q e^{At}$, then
$\dot{\phi}(t) = A^T e^{A^T t} Q e^{At} + e^{A^T t} Q e^{At} A $.

$\phi(0) = Q$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} \phi(t) = 0$ since $A$ is Hurwitz.

Let $P = \int_0^{\infty} \phi(t) dt$ (since $A$ is Hurwitz, it is not too hard to show that $t \mapsto \|\phi(t)\|$ is integrable).

Hence $\int_0^{\infty} \dot{\phi}(t) dt = -Q$, this
gives $A^TP + PA = -Q$.